# Different calculation result

Tags: javascript, python, node.js

Explain to me why the result of the following calculation is different:

Python:

```
tmp = 4235635936 << 0 #4235635936
```

JS

```
let tmp = 4235635936 << 0 // -59331360
```

Question - how do I get the same result in python as in js ?

Comment: Because those are different languages with different semantics?

Comment: Python has infinite-precision integers, JavaScript doesn't.

Comment: Bitwise operations in JS always operate on 32 bit numbers. If a number is larger than 32 bit, it's truncated.

Comment: @akx I understand this, but nevertheless, how do I bring the result of execution in python to the result in js

Comment: @Barmar This doesn't have to do with precision but signedness.

Comment: @VLAZ the number isn't larger than 32 bits. It is larger than 31 bits + sign bit though. :)

Comment: @AKX yes, JS bitwise operations only work on 32-bit signed two's complement binary number. Didn't think I needed to be THAT precise while looking for one of the ***many*** dupes on this exact same topic. Literally many have asked why bitwise operations differ between Python and JS.

Comment: @Barmar JavaScript doesn’t _by default_ — it just requires a suffix to opt in to that. `4235635936n << 0n === 4235635936n`.

Comment: Related: [difference between JavaScript bit-wise operator code and Python bit-wise operator code](/q/41610186/4642212).

Answer (score 0):

The binary representation for both numbers is the same. One is signed, the other is unsigned.

```
>>> struct.pack("<i", -59331360)
b'\xe0\xacv\xfc'
>>> struct.pack("<I", 4235635936)
b'\xe0\xacv\xfc'
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

in JS, the bitwise operators and shift operators operate on 32-bit ints, and your example overflows the 32-bit capacity.

In Python there's no capacity limit for integers, so you get the actual value.